# Session getting terminated after 30+ minutes of inactivity automatically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project where I need to have login system with multiple users where each user will login and save form entries in a file. I have maximum 10 internal users and this project is only for internal users.

Here is the idea -

- I have a simple form with two textbox and one save button. There is also a `logout` link on this page. This page is called `index.php`.
- Once a user logins successfully on `login.php` page then he will be redirected to `index.php` page which has above form.
- Now user will type some entries in the textbox on `index.php` page and click save button. Once save button is clicked, data will be saved in a file as json and alert box will pop up showing data written in the file (or if there is any issue writing in file).
- Once I click `logout` button, then it redirects back to `login.php` page.

Now this whole system works with multiple users where only **one user** is allowed to save entries in a file at a given time if multiple users are logged in.

**Case 1:**

1. If "userA" logins successfully for the first time, then he can save the form entries in a file.
2. "userA" logs out.

**Case 2:**

1. Now "userB" logs in successfully. Then he should be able to save the form entries in the same file by overwriting it.
2. "userB" logs out.

**Case 3:**

1. Now "userA" logs in successfully again. And he is working on making changes in the form.
2. And "userB" tries to log in suddenly from different browser. Then he should be able to see a prompt telling `userA is logged in. Do you want to take over?`. If he clicks `ok` button then he should login successfully. But if he click `cancel` button then he will not be able to login.
3. Let's say if "userB" clicks ok button and he logs in now as well. At this moment both "userA" and "userB" are logged in. So as soon as "userB" logs in then if "userA" tries to click save button in the form trying to save entries in the file then it should popup telling your "Write access is revoked since userB is logged in now". So userA can still see the form but should not be able to save anything since his write access is revoked.

**Case 4:**

1. If "userC" also logs in successfully. Now we have all three users logged in. At this time only "userC" should be able to make changes as write access will be revoked for "userA" and "userB".
2. But if "userC" logs out then "userB" should be able to save form if he tries to save. Because "userB" access was revoked last so he will get his access back if "userC" logs out but "userA" access will be revoked still.

**Problem Statement**

Is there something in php server which can terminate my session after a particular period of time.

Comment: search for *php session lifetime* for all the answers

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. Interesting thing is when I run on my mac I am using XAMPP and in my php.ini file I also have 24 minutes default but it never logs me out at all but when I run this exact code on my company server then it logs me out after 24 minutes looks like. Why this is different between my mac vs my company server? If this is about this file then it should work similar in both the cases right?

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned this in my question but since I thought maybe it is not needed. Sorry about that on my end. I will add this detail though. Now I am thinking maybe mac php.ini file is not taken into the consideration for some reason when using XAMPP server?

Comment: I've deleted comments regarding the other server now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the server configuration or the relevant directives http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime in php.ini

Typically the default is 24 minutes (1440 seconds), but your webhost may have altered the default to something else.

**UPDATE**

as per OP new comments.

If session is stored in files give the permission 777 to storage directory in you server. If you are storing the session in database then we have to find out other alternate solution.

Comment: I see. Interesting thing is when I run on my mac I am using XAMPP and in my php.ini file I also have 24 minutes default but it never logs me out at all but when I run this exact code on my company server then it logs me out after 24 minutes looks like. Why this is different between my mac vs my company server? If this is about this file then it should work similar in both the cases right?

Comment: Now I am thinking maybe mac `php.ini` file is not taken into the consideration for some reason when using XAMPP server?

Comment: you mean to say I give file permission to my local mac php.ini file?

Comment: there is big difference between local and live server,,, you need to give permission 777 to session directory in live server. not local/mac